# type name is not allowed on porting Android to windows in cocos 2.0.4

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x

I am porting my android app to windows platform using cocos 2.0.4, as i build I got

```
error: C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
```

but it also shows **type name not allowed** for: ccColor3B in particular line

```
m_sprStar->setColor( (ccColor3B)    {m_iColRed,m_iColGreen,m_iColBlue});



void HorseRunObstacle::animateCollectables()
{
 if(m_sprStar==NULL)
{
   // if(m_iObstacleId!=OBSTACLE_COIN)
    {
        m_sprStar = CCSprite::create("HorseRun_Resource/Images/starparticle.png");
        m_sprStar->setPosition(m_sprObstacle->getPosition());
        m_sprStar->setScale(0.5f);
        if(m_iObstacleId==OBSTACLE_COIN)

m_sprStar->setColor( (ccColor3B)    {m_iColRed,m_iColGreen,m_iColBlue});

        m_ptrGameLayer->addChild(m_sprStar,0);

        CCActionInterval* scaleUp = CCScaleTo::create(0.2f, 3.14f);
        CCActionInterval* scaleDn = CCScaleTo::create(0.2f, 2.0f);
        CCFiniteTimeAction* seq = CCSequence::create(scaleUp,scaleDn,NULL);
        m_sprStar->runAction(seq);
    }

}
```

I have tried giving **using namespace cocos2d;** and also **cocos2d::** but of no use ..,Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create structures "on the fly" like that. Instead create a temporary object like

```
m_sprStar->setColor(Color3B(m_iColRed,m_iColGreen,m_iColBlue));
```

Note: Passing temporary objects like this works only for functions that take its argument *by value* or by *constant reference*.